# Display CAML Result In SharePoint page

Tags: javascript, caml, query

How would I display the result of a CAML query via javascript on a SharePoint page? I'm trying to use this result in inline HTML similar to this:

```
<h5> Current OnCall: [CAML Result]</h5>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the `result of a CAML query  via javascript`.  Are you trying to fetch data from SharePoint list and you want to show that on SharePoint page ? can you elaborate it more....

Comment: i have a CAML query that pulls the current on call person from a list. I need to display this persons name on a SharePoint page. I was thinking the best way may be to use JS and a variable, but i was having a tough time getting it to work so I thought I would throw out the question for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You may put the entire CAML Query result in a variable, then you can add it to the DOM as such:

HTML:

```
<h5 id="camltext"></h5>
```

JavaScript:

```
var camlResult = JSON.stringify(data.d.results); //find CAMLResults from JSOM
var textnode = document.createTextNode(camlResult );
document.getElementById('camltext').appendChild(textnode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this looks like it's pointing me in the right direction. Do I add the CAML query?